# How do I calculate monthly compound interest with additional monthly deposits in Google Sheets?

Tags: savings, compound-interest, spreadsheet

I'm trying to figure out how to write a formula and/or use a function to calculate the following in Google Sheets.

John deposits $1,000.00 into a savings account on Dec 31st. John also deposits $100 on the 1st of every month and will do so for the next 10 years. The interest rate is fixed @ 4% for 10 years and compounds monthly. How much will John have after ten years?

```
$1,0000 principal. 
$1,200 per year for 10 years.
Total deposits $13,000.
```

I currently have everything figured out with the exception of the monthly contribution. Screenshot of the data is below. How would I update to include the monthly $100 contribution? Thanks for your help!

```
=C6*(1+C7/C9)^(C9*C8)
```

[image]

This solution worked, `=fv(C7/C9,C8*C9,-C10)+C6*power(1+C7/C9,C8*C9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply treat this as two different investment and just sum them. 1000$ one time at 4% plus 100% per month at 4% both for 10 years.

Final value would be `=FV(C7/C9,C8*C9,-C10)+C6*power(1+C7,C8)` or $16,205.22

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I compared the result to https://www.investor.gov/financial-tools-calculators/calculators/compound-interest-calculator and noticed a discrepancy of roughly $10. Do you know what would cause this?

Comment: Found it, `=fv(C7/C9,C8*C9,-C10)+C6*power(1+C7/C9,C8*C9)`. Needed to update the 2nd formula to include monthly compounding).